# GeoServer + GeoWebCache - save PNG8 format cache with PNG extension?

Tags: geoserver

I want to reduce the size of the cache memory that GeoWebCache makes. The cache is in PNG8 format, but the request from the client is in PNG format (FORMAT=image%2Fpng) and I can't change it. How do I configure GeoWebCache to save PNG8 with the .png extension? I can rename all files (tile.png8 -> tile.png), but perhaps there is a correct solution to my problem?

request

```
http://192.168.0.163:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wms?STYLES=&VERSION=1.3.0&SRS=EPSG%3A3857&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&LAYERS=cite%3AALLGroup&EXCEPTIONS=INIMAGE&SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&CRS=EPSG%3A900913&BBOX=5290665.3462613,7817367.7529044,5293111.3311661,7819813.7378091&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256
```

I want to store the cache in png format like google map.

```
Driver: PNG/Portable Network Graphics
Files: 3.png
Size is 128, 128
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0,  128.0)
Upper Right (  128.0,    0.0)
Lower Right (  128.0,  128.0)
Center      (   64.0,   64.0)
Band 1 Block=128x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Palette
  Color Table (RGB with 256 entries)
    0: 84,88,72,255
    1: 76,88,72,255
    2: 80,88,72,255
    3: 72,84,68,255
    4: 76,84,68,255
    5: 84,92,76,255
    6: 88,96,80,255
    7: 68,80,64,255
    8: 155,159,139,255
    9: 80,92,76,255
   10: 88,92,76,255
   11: 84,96,80,255
   12: 92,100,84,255
   13: 88,96,76,255
   14: 116,120,100,255
   15: 92,104,88,255
   16: 100,112,96,255
   17: 100,104,84,255
   18: 64,76,60,255
   19: 96,104,88,255
   20: 167,171,151,255
   21: 187,187,175,255
   22: 68,84,68,255
   23: 72,80,64,255
   24: 84,92,72,255
   25: 68,84,64,255
   26: 104,108,88,255
   27: 100,108,92,255
   28: 147,151,131,255
   29: 92,96,80,255
   30: 88,88,72,255
   31: 171,175,155,255
   32: 80,84,68,255
   33: 199,195,179,255
   34: 72,88,68,255
   35: 92,100,80,255
   36: 76,92,72,255
   37: 108,116,100,255
   38: 104,112,96,255
   39: 96,100,80,255
   40: 179,179,167,255
   41: 112,116,96,255
   42: 163,167,147,255
   43: 112,120,104,255
   44: 108,112,92,255
   45: 96,108,92,255
   46: 76,88,68,255
   47: 143,147,135,255
   48: 80,88,68,255
   49: 92,92,76,255
   50: 96,104,84,255
   51: 116,124,108,255
   52: 72,88,72,255
   53: 88,100,84,255
   54: 108,120,104,255
   55: 96,108,88,255
   56: 120,120,100,255
   57: 104,104,88,255
   58: 120,124,104,255
   59: 76,80,64,255
   60: 64,80,64,255
   61: 100,104,88,255
   62: 207,207,187,255
   63: 100,112,92,255
   64: 131,131,112,255
   65: 135,135,116,255
   66: 147,151,135,255
   67: 131,135,116,255
   68: 96,100,84,255
   69: 80,92,72,255
   70: 143,143,131,255
   71: 112,116,100,255
   72: 88,92,72,255
   73: 120,131,116,255
   74: 131,135,112,255
   75: 139,139,120,255
   76: 56,72,52,255
   77: 179,179,159,255
   78: 68,76,60,255
   79: 96,96,80,255
   80: 116,120,104,255
   81: 96,108,96,255
   82: 76,92,76,255
   83: 104,112,92,255
   84: 104,116,100,255
   85: 108,108,92,255
   86: 124,131,116,255
   87: 48,64,56,255
   88: 128,131,112,255
   89: 100,108,88,255
   90: 100,100,84,255
   91: 112,124,108,255
   92: 92,96,76,255
   93: 76,84,64,255
   94: 72,84,64,255
   95: 88,100,80,255
   96: 116,116,100,255
   97: 84,96,76,255
   98: 64,84,64,255
   99: 124,124,108,255
  100: 84,88,68,255
  101: 60,72,56,255
  102: 108,116,96,255
  103: 120,120,104,255
  104: 108,112,96,255
  105: 112,112,92,255
  106: 116,116,96,255
  107: 108,108,88,255
  108: 147,147,124,255
  109: 72,84,72,255
  110: 116,128,112,255
  111: 84,84,68,255
  112: 84,100,84,255
  113: 88,92,80,255
  114: 124,135,120,255
  115: 112,112,96,255
  116: 60,76,56,255
  117: 76,88,76,255
  118: 135,139,116,255
  119: 104,104,84,255
  120: 128,128,108,255
  121: 120,128,112,255
  122: 72,76,60,255
  123: 159,163,147,255
  124: 124,128,108,255
  125: 139,147,131,255
  126: 64,80,60,255
  127: 147,155,139,255
  128: 139,143,124,255
  129: 139,143,120,255
  130: 128,131,116,255
  131: 88,100,88,255
  132: 135,143,128,255
  133: 128,131,108,255
  134: 80,96,80,255
  135: 116,124,104,255
  136: 104,108,92,255
  137: 92,104,84,255
  138: 131,131,116,255
  139: 128,139,124,255
  140: 100,100,80,255
  141: 68,80,68,255
  142: 76,84,72,255
  143: 151,155,135,255
  144: 120,124,108,255
  145: 84,100,80,255
  146: 76,80,68,255
  147: 143,147,131,255
  148: 108,112,100,255
  149: 131,139,120,255
  150: 151,151,135,255
  151: 143,143,124,255
  152: 68,88,68,255
  153: 120,124,100,255
  154: 135,139,120,255
  155: 60,80,60,255
  156: 124,124,112,255
  157: 120,128,108,255
  158: 151,155,139,255
  159: 215,215,195,255
  160: 124,131,112,255
  161: 135,139,124,255
  162: 80,84,64,255
  163: 72,92,72,255
  164: 112,124,104,255
  165: 80,96,76,255
  166: 80,92,80,255
  167: 155,163,147,255
  168: 155,155,135,255
  169: 80,84,72,255
  170: 84,88,76,255
  171: 135,139,128,255
  172: 159,163,143,255
  173: 68,80,60,255
  174: 112,120,100,255
  175: 151,151,139,255
  176: 92,96,84,255
  177: 131,135,124,255
  178: 131,135,120,255
  179: 64,76,64,255
  180: 124,135,116,255
  181: 143,143,120,255
  182: 96,100,88,255
  183: 116,120,96,255
  184: 124,128,104,255
  185: 96,96,76,255
  186: 104,116,96,255
  187: 120,120,108,255
  188: 68,72,56,255
  189: 223,219,207,255
  190: 40,56,40,255
  191: 143,147,128,255
  192: 108,120,100,255
  193: 163,163,139,255
  194: 64,72,56,255
  195: 92,104,80,255
  196: 108,112,88,255
  197: 135,135,120,255
  198: 84,84,72,255
  199: 139,139,124,255
  200: 92,100,76,255
  201: 139,143,131,255
  202: 92,92,72,255
  203: 143,147,124,255
  204: 72,76,64,255
  205: 159,159,151,255
  206: 124,128,112,255
  207: 96,104,80,255
  208: 112,116,92,255
  209: 80,80,64,255
  210: 139,139,131,255
  211: 124,131,108,255
  212: 116,128,108,255
  213: 120,124,112,255
  214: 72,80,68,255
  215: 88,100,76,255
  216: 131,131,108,255
  217: 76,96,76,255
  218: 84,92,80,255
  219: 100,104,80,255
  220: 108,120,112,255
  221: 80,88,76,255
  222: 239,239,223,255
  223: 227,231,211,255
  224: 135,135,124,255
  225: 84,92,68,255
  226: 135,143,131,255
  227: 28,52,40,255
  228: 100,108,84,255
  229: 128,124,104,255
  230: 155,155,131,255
  231: 139,147,124,255
  232: 131,131,124,255
  233: 48,76,68,255
  234: 84,96,72,255
  235: 112,120,96,255
  236: 68,76,64,255
  237: 128,135,116,255
  238: 80,92,68,255
  239: 80,80,60,255
  240: 72,80,60,255
  241: 100,116,100,255
  242: 28,60,52,255
  243: 76,88,64,255
  244: 72,92,76,255
  245: 131,139,116,255
  246: 88,92,68,255
  247: 20,40,32,255
  248: 84,88,64,255
  249: 139,143,128,255
  250: 92,96,72,255
  251: 128,135,120,255
  252: 80,88,64,255
  253: 12,44,36,255
  254: 24,52,44,255
  255: 16,48,44,255
```

Comment: I fear there is nothing that you can do on the GeoServer and GWC side but having an option to save png8 as .png feels like a reasonable configuration option. Right now I think that rewriting the requests that come into TomCat or Jetty would be be quite a good solution.

Comment: the problem with changing the endings is that `image/png` and `image/png8` are different formats and the client should respect that. I'd file a bug against the client

Comment: @Ian Turton I agree, but how do I store a PNG cache with an 8-bit color depth?

Comment: You would need to write some new code. Or maybe run rgb2pct.py on them though in my test the size goes from 62k to 1.3M when I do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks. Then I will try to create a PNG cache with a color depth of 24 bits, and then convert the files to 8 bits using gdal tools, leaving the png extension.